# Flex Data Binding problem

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding

```
<mx:Label text="{(item1 as INewsItem).displayName}"/>
```

For the above code in Flex, I get this warning :

**: Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to item1.**
Why? How to Fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Prutswonder.
Actually item1 is declared as a getter,
like this :

```
public function get item1()
```

So, I had to prepend it like this :

```
[Bindable] public function get item1()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you define a `[Bindable] function get item1()` you'll also need to define a `function set item1()`, otherwise Flex wouldn't know when to dispatch a change event. Or you could manually dispatch the change event:

```
[Bindable(event="item1Change"]
public function get item1() { return ... }
```

And whenever something on item1 changes you dispatch an event:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("item1Change"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning is displayed because the databinding will not be refreshed automatically when `item1` is updated. If you do want this behaviour, then you cannot use this databinding and will have to update the label text manually when `item1` is changed.